# Getting sp value from another sp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Although I have looked around a little bit but no luck yet

I am using SQL Server. Here is the whole scenario.

I have an old legacy sp (which I cannot change due to lot of dependencies and other issue) which doesn't return any value nor it accepts any output parameter, It just select a value as

```
Create sp myoldsp (@paramentes)
as
...
select scope_identity() as autoID
...
```

Now I am writing another sp where i need this autoID values, i have tried

```
exec myoldsp @parameters
select scope_identity()
```

and also tried

```
Declare @autoid int
exec @autoid=myoldsp @parametes
```

but unable to get that returned value. Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a temporary table, and insert into it.

```
declare @t table (id int)

insert @t (id)
exec myoldsp @parameters
```

(What you were trying - `exec @autoid=myoldsp` - would return the value from a `return [val]` statement)